# Grab the printerdriver version with powershell 2.0

Tags: powershell, printing, driver, wmi, powershell-2.0

I have to grab the printerdriver version with powershell vom a printserver on windows server 2008 R2.

[image: Print Management]

I know the opportunity to get this value out of the system with the Get-PrinterDriver cmdlet (Example, works perfectly on WinSrv2012R2 with PS v4.0: [Get-Printerdriver Driver Version](http://blog.powershell.no/2013/09/08/get-printerdriver-driver-version/)). The problem is, that my system is in production and has only powershell v2.0 installed on it, where this cmdlet doesn't already exist.

I already get the name of the printerdriver with powershell and the WMI class "win32_printerdriver" out of the system.

```
Get-WmiObject -ComputerName localhost -Class "win32_printerdriver" | select Name
```

Is there maybe a possibility, to get the driverversion with WMI? I search through google results, but there are only several results where people get the version of the unidrv.dll or pscript.dll. Not the actual printerdriver version from print management.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to workaround this peace of code:

```
(Get-Item $((Get-WmiObject -ComputerName localhost -Class "win32_printerdriver").driverpath)).VersionInfo
```